# How to check if several properties exist in an object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object `result` that can be received like for example:

```
const firstRowVoucher = result[0]['Voucher ID'] || result[0]['voucher_id'] || result[0]['VOUCHER_ID'];
const firstRowInvoice = result[0]['Invoice'] || result[0]['INVOICE'] || result[0]['invoice'];

if (firstRowVoucher && firstRowInvoice){
  //do some code
}

result.forEach((element) => {
  const elementVoucher =  element['Voucher ID'] || result[0]['voucher_id'] || element['VOUCHER_ID'];
  const elementStatus =  element['Invoice'] || result[0]['INVOICE'] || element['invoice'];
 
  if(elementVoucher && elementStatus){
    // do some other stuff
  }
});
```

It works, but it seems a little messy because there are lot of other words and conditionals.

Is there a way to check in a list of `names` if the object has those `names` as attributes? In order to get a better maintenance and better readability.

Maybe using an object array or something like this:

```
 const fields = {
    unit: ['Unit' || 'unit' || 'UNIT'],
    voucherID: ['Voucher ID' || 'voucher_id' || 'VOUCHER_ID'],
    invoice: ['Invoice' || 'INVOICE' || 'invoice'],
    status: ['status' || 'STATUS' || 'Status'],
    invoiceGrossAmount: [
      'Invoice Gross Amount' ||
        'Invoice_Gross_Amount' ||
        'invoice gross amount' ||
        'invoice_gross_amount',
    ],
    currency: ['Currency' || 'currency'],
    SupplierID: [
      'Supplier ID' || 'supplier_id' || 'Supplier_Id' || 'Supplier_ID',
    ],
    PONumber: ['PO Number' || 'PO_Number' || 'po_number' || 'po number'],
    status: ['status' || 'Status' || 'STATUS'],
  };
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have access to the "result"? Ideally these keys should be standardized

Comment: Thanks! Not ideally, this results comes from an imported file, and could change between different formats from the same type of file. this is are large files.

Comment: If you only want to check if key exists inside object, you can use `Object.keys(your-object)`, to create an array with all keys inside object, and then use `.some(key => key.toLowerCase() === <seach-string>.toLowerCase())`. Doing it, you will turn all keys inside the array into lower case, and then compare with your search string in lower case as well. But as Gabriel said on comment above, may you can have exactly which keys you will receive as result, and make it a little bit more easier. You can also replace `_` for any other character, if you want to

Comment: In your `.forEach()` loop, why are you checking element for some values and `result[0]` for the other value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend transforming your result objects into one specific format.
One way to achieve this would be setting all your keys to snake_case

```
const snakeCaseResults = result.map((obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce(
    (res, [key, value]) => ({ ...res, [key.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '_')]: value }),
    {}
  )
)
```

this way you can always access your result using snake_case

E.g.

```
const firstRowVoucher = snakeCaseResults[0]['voucher_id'];
const firstRowInvoice = snakeCaseResults[0]['invoice'];
```

Comment: @dMd - See my answer above that collapses multiple spaces to a single canonical space before comparing.

Comment: I just changed this line to match all the spaces.
        [key.toLowerCase().replace(/ +/g, ' ').replace(' ', '_')]: value,

Answer (score 0):

You can make a little helper function that checks the various versions for you so you only have that code in one place:

```
// pass any case example with optional space or underline
function getField(obj, example) {
    // create canonical lowerCase version with single space delimiters
    const exSpace = example.replace(/\s+|_+/g, " ").toLowerCase();
    let props = Object.entries(obj);
    for (let propName of props) {
        // take candicate property name and convert it to canonical
        // form of lowercase, space delimited, spaces and underscores collapsed
        const propCanonical = propName.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+|_+/g, " ");
        if (propCanonical === exSpace) {
            return obj[propName];
        }
    }
    return null;        
}
```

And, then use it like this:

```
const firstRowVoucher = getField(result[0], 'Voucher ID');
const firstRowInvoice = getField(result[0], 'Invoice');
```

FYI, the very fact that you don't know what the form of the field name is seems like some bad code somewhere before this that should be cleaned up.  If you really have no control over the quality of the input, then maybe you should just sanitize the whole input before you every handle it so once you get `result`, it's only using standardized field names.